# Connect Spring Boot app to Oozie dashboard

Tags: spring-boot, oozie

We have a spring boot app which runs batch jobs. At the heart of it, its just long running sql queries.

I want to tie up the jobs to an oozie dashboard. But I have no idea where to begin.

I can change the spring boot app to talk to oozie, any examples out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the oozie Java API dependency

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.oozie</groupId>
       <artifactId>oozie-client</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.0</version>   
</dependency>
```

and send jobs to Oozie as the documentation says
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_Examples.html

(Java API Example section)

Also can use the REST API.